# why 15% + 85% does not give 100%. Web layout HTML/css

Tags: html, css

Absolute beginner in HTML. It is a layout question. I have a header of `width 100%`
Than I want to have a `nav` section for navigation which should be `15%` of the page, than the rest `85%` should display some content. Ending webpage with `footer`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="fr, 09 okt 2015 06:20:07 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mateusz.css">
    <title>Nowa strona</title>


  </head>
  <body>
<div id = "header"> dada</div>
<div id = "nav" class="container"> <h1> ma </h1> </div>
<div id = "section" class="flex-column"> WTH </div>
<div id = "footer"> M </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

style:

```
body { margin:40px;
padding:5px }

#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%

}

#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;

}

#section {
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    width:85%;
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:5px;  
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;
   width:100%;  

}
```

But I receive that which I interpret as the 15% and 85% is not equal to 100% (WTH is lower in relation to `nav`? I tested 83% and than is correct but the "red" does not overlap fully with the `header`

[image]

What should I do to make it right?

Comment: Please include your full code (CSS and HTML) to allow us to reproduce your issue. It's probably because you have applied `padding` to the elements.

Comment: because of padding check BOX-MODEL

Comment: `padding:5px;` That's why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the padding gets added to your container width. So its 85% width + 5px on each side which results in a greater width than 85%.

You can fix that by adding the following code: `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
#nav {
line-height:30px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
height:300px;
width:15%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;

}

#section {
float:left;
background-color: red;
width:85%;
display:inline-block; 
padding:5px;  
box-sizing:border-box;
margin-left:-5px; /* margin-left: -5px has to be done to fix the display:inline-block; default margin*/
}
```

In addition I wouldn't recommend to use inline-bock and float for one element. You should decide on either float or inline-block.

Answer (score 4):

Write this in the section and nav:

```
  #section , #nav { box-sizing:border-box; }
```

That's because the padding is counted as the total width (and the border too), but without it the padding and the border is incrementing the width

And please, don't mix floats with inline-block elements.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `box-sizing` to all elements. It will help you to calculate `width`, `height`, `margin`, `padding`, `border` easily.

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Above '*' selects all elements and it will apply this on every elements you'll have.

Read this for more information - https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

When the `nav` is `float: left`, the `section` should also be `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `padding`. So change with this one.

```
#nav {
line-height:30px;
background-color:#eeeeee;
height:300px;
width:15%;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
#section {
float:left;
background-color: red;
width:85%;
display:inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `padding:5px;` in your `#section` and `#nav` classes